# Is it possible to have a "fixed sidenav"and a scrolling left side using angular-material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I've been trying to work through this for the last few hours and just cannot get this working. I am trying to create 3 columns, let's call them columns A, B, C.

Column A and B I would like to scroll together as one unit and take up the full height of the site. Column C I would like to scroll independently and not scroll when column A and B are scrolled.

Unfortunately, I cannot create a setup that meets all of those conditions and maintains full height.

In this plnkr below you can see that the green and gray sections should be full height but are not. I feel like it's close but the last bit is driving me nuts!

http://plnkr.co/edit/jPpZhFLP3e1fgNvDLFQD?p=preview

```
<body layout="row" style="min-height:100%" >

  <md-content flex layout="row" layout-fill>

    <div class="side-a" flex layout-fill>
      <p>lots of content that requires scrolling...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="middle" flex layout-fill>
      <p>lots of content that requires scrolling...</p> 
    </div>

  </md-content>

  <md-sidenav layout-fill flex layout="column" class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2 side-b" md-component-id="left>
      <p>lots of content that requires scrolling...</p>
   </md-sidenav>

</body>
```

Thanks. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap your column content in another div inside of your columns and use relative/absolute positioning. i.e.

```
<md-content flex layout="row" layout-fill>

  <div flex layout-fill style="position: relative;">
    <div class="side-a" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">
      <p>lots of content that requires scrolling...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div flex layout-fill style="position: relative;">
    <div class="middle" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">
      <p>lots of content that requires scrolling...</p> 
    </div>
  </div>

</md-content>
```

Note that the classes have moved from the column itself to the inner div.

This works because the absolute positioned div will expand to fit any content within it. The downside to this method is that if one column is shorter than the other then the shorter column wont span the remaining height.